# Eulers method to approximate gravity in one dimension

Tags: runge-kutta-methods, eulers-method

I am going to program Eulers method in Octave to approximate gravity in 1-dimension. I understand the formula for Eulers method, which is equal to:

[image]

What I don't understand is what my function $f(t,y)$ is in this case. What do I have to insert into the formula to get my next $y$-point?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with approximating gravitation in $1d$?

Comment: I meant the object is falling in one dimension. Just straight down. So I have to approximate this somehow: https://gyazo.com/ae8b964e8f851aa12d1eb20f68a5a0f2 And maybe with initial velocity as well.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the scale, you have
$$
\ddot x=a(t,x)=-g
$$
or
$$
\ddot x=a(t,x)=-\frac{GM}{(R+x)^2}
$$
where $G$ is the gravitational constant, $M$ the mass of Earth and $R$ its radius.

As this is second order, a first order system would have the form
$$
\binom{\dot x}{\dot v}=f(t,(x,v))=\binom{v}{a(t,x)}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Euler's method is usually used to discretize systems of explicit first order ordinary differential equations. Such a system is given by $$y'(x) = f(x,y(x))$$ where $f$ is in general a vector-valued, continuous function and we are looking for the function $y(x)$. In general, enough initial conditions are provided and we call this an initial value problem. In classical mechanics, the systems originate from Newton's second law, that the sum of the acting forces is equal to mass times acceleration of your object in consideration. In your case we have $$-mg = ma = mx''(t) \Leftrightarrow x''(t) = -g$$ However this is a second order equation and we must therefore write it as a system os first order to solve it using Euler. We get $$\begin{bmatrix} x_1(t)\\x_2(t)\end{bmatrix}'= \begin{bmatrix} x_2(t)\\-g\end{bmatrix}$$ so we have $$f(t,x(t)) = \begin{bmatrix} x_2(t)\\-g\end{bmatrix}$$ Here is an example code:

```
y0 = [10;-1];
t0 = 0;
tN = 1;
N = 10;
g = 9.81;
f = @(t,x) [x(2);-g];
[t,x] = euler(f,t0,tN,y0,N);
plot(t,x(1,:));
grid on;
```

using this implementation of the euler method:

```
function [ t,y ] = euler( f,t0,tN,y0,N )
h = (tN - t0)/N;
t = t0:h:tN;
y = zeros(length(y0),N+1);
y(:,1) = y0;
for k = 1:N
    y(:,k+1) = y(:,k) + h * f(t(k),y(:,k));
end
end
```

implemented in MATLAB. I used initial velocity $-1$ and initial place $10$. It produces:

[image]

**Analytical Solution.** Consider the IVP

$$\begin{bmatrix} x_1(t)\\x_2(t)\end{bmatrix}'= \begin{bmatrix} x_2(t)\\-g\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_2(t)\\0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 0\\-g\end{bmatrix} \qquad x(0) = \begin{bmatrix} x_0\\v_0\end{bmatrix}$$ From the last coordinate it is obvious, that $$x_2(t) = -gt + c$$ for some real constant $c$. Furthermore, from the first coordinate we get $$x'_1(t) = -gt + c \Leftrightarrow x_1(t) = -\frac{1}{2}gt^2 + ct + d$$ for some real constant $d$. by the initial conditions, we get the linear system $$x_0 = d  \qquad v_0 = c$$ Hence our solution to the IVP is the vector-valued function $$x(t) = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{2}gt^2 + v_0t + x_0\\-gt + v_0 \end{bmatrix}$$ where the first coordinate corresponds to the place and the second to the velocity. Adding this in the plot above yields

[image]

Where red is the euler method, blue is the analytical solution and black my implementation of the step-size controlled DOPRI5 algorithm for reference (which can be found [here](https://github.com/TheGeekGreek/numerical_analysis/blob/master/src/DOPRI5.m)).

Comment: I still don't quite understand. Since the gravity is a second derivative of position it becomes a second order differential equation. So if you hang on, I am going to quickly teach myself how to convert second order differentials into first order ones.

Comment: @DavidLund Yes, that would be nice since it is crucial to understand how you derive the correct function $f$.

Comment: I don't really understand it yet. I manage to take a higher order differential equation, and split into a system of first order differential equations. I got the same result as you. Still, I don't know how to solve a system of first order equations? Is this a necessity as well? Because I get very stumped when I have a vector as an answer or just two equations instead of one. I am stumped on the math part of what to do next. If I were to do it by hand for example.

Comment: @DavidLund First of all, Euler's method does only apply to first order systems. You cannot solve second or higher order systems with it without any modification (see for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration the Leapfrog method for second order ODEs). To solve such system analytically is a whole other point and is in most cases impossible. However I will add a theoretical part in my answer. Linear systems have a full theory developed and can be solved analytically, please read some literature about this topic.